# How Ellipse to Ellipse intersection?

Tags: java, intersection, java-2d, shapes, ellipse

I'm using JAVA.

```
Ellipse2D s1=new Ellipse2D.Float(0,0,100,100);
System.out.println(s1.intersects(99, 30, 100, 100));
```

Should return false but it return true. How to find intersection between 2 ellipse?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CADEMIA](http://www.cademia.org) has an useful api which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.cademia.org/frontend/index.php?folder_id=257). The class [cib.util.geo.Geo2D](http://www.cademia.org/frontend/doc/cib/util/geo/Geo2D.html) has a method [Geo2D#intersection](http://www.cademia.org/frontend/doc/cib/util/geo/Geo2D.html#intersection%28java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D,%20java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D%29) which calculates the intersection points between two ellipses.

Hope this will help you. Thanks.

Comment: How do i get CADEMIA library?

Comment: The location of the library is http://www.cademia.org/frontend/media/zip/2_0/CADEMIA_2.1RC4.zip . download->extract->use the .jar file.

Comment: @TapasBose hey I know it's been 10 years but do you happen to know of an alternative way to get this or a different solution?